# How to query NOAA for historical daily temperature averages using rnoaa?

Tags: r, noaa, rnoaa

I'm trying to find the historical average temperature between a range of dates using NOAA data and comparing to the long term average temperatures.

I'm using the [rnoaa](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnoaa/rnoaa.pdf) package and have hit a bit of a snag. For long term averages, I have been successful using the following syntax:

```
library('rnoaa')

start_date = "2010-01-15"
end_date = "2010-11-14"
station_id = "USW00093738"

weather_data <- ncdc(datasetid='NORMAL_DLY', stationid=paste0('GHCND:',station_id),
                     datatypeid='dly-tavg-normal',
                     startdate = start_date, enddate = end_date,limit=365)
```

This lets me parse `weather_data$data` for the long term average temperatures for that given station between January 15th and November 14th.

However, I can't seem to find the right dataset or datatype for historical average temperatures. I'd like to get the same data as the code above except with the actual daily average temperatures for those days. Any idea how to query this? I've been at it for a few hours and have had no luck.

Something I tried was the following:

```
weather_data <- ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', stationid=paste0('GHCND:',station_id),
                     startdate = start_date, enddate = end_date,limit=365)

uniq_d_types = unique(weather_data$data$datatype)
View(uniq_d_types)
```

This let me see the unique data types in the GHCND dataset but none of the data types seemed to be daily average temperatures. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "actual average temperatures?" How does this vary from the historical averages, which are calculated over a 30 year period?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @LenGreski. What I mean is the average daily temperature for that given day. So let's say there was a high of 80 F and a low of 50 F but if you were to get the average across the whole day it was closer to 65 F or so. If I saw the 30 year average for that day was 50 F, I'd know that it was unseasonably warm.

Comment: Are you asking for an average calculated from 24 hourly temperatures readings, the difference between the high and low for a given day, or some other formula?

Comment: @LenGreski Thanks again. Correct, the average calculated from 24 hourly temperature readings would work perfectly.

Comment: You'll need to access the hourly data and aggregate it yourself, because  average daily temperature is not saved to the daily data set. See my answer below for an example of how to obtain the average for hourly temperatures from the NOAA data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to grab historical (meaning actual, on the day specified-- not long term average) weather data from the NOAA's ISD database. USAF and WBAN values can be found by looking through the `isd-history.csv` file found here:

ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa

Here's an example query.

`out <- isd(usaf='724030', wban = '93738', year=2018)`

This will grab a years worth of ~hourly weather data from ISD mapping. You can then parse/process this data however you see fit (e.g. for daily average temperatures like I did).

Answer (score 2):

In order to obtain average daily actual temperatures from the NOAA data using the `rnoaa` package, one must use the hourly data and aggregate it by day.  Hourly NOAA data is in the `NORMAL_HLY` data set, and the required data type is `HLY-TEMP-NORMAL`.

```
library('rnoaa')
library(lubridate)
options(noaakey = "obtain key from NOAA website")

start_date = "2010-01-15"
end_date = "2010-01-31"
station_id = "USW00093738"

weather_data <- ncdc(datasetid='NORMAL_HLY', stationid=paste0('GHCND:',station_id),
                     datatypeid = "HLY-TEMP-NORMAL",
                     startdate = start_date, enddate = end_date,limit=500)
data <- weather_data$data 

data$year <- year(data$date)
data$month <- month(data$date)
data$day <- day(data$date)
# summarize to average daily temps
aggregate(value ~ year + month + day,mean,data = data)
```

...and the output:

```
> aggregate(value ~ year + month + day,mean,data = data)
   year month day    value
1  2010     1  15 323.5417
2  2010     1  16 322.8750
3  2010     1  17 323.4167
4  2010     1  18 323.7500
5  2010     1  19 323.2083
6  2010     1  20 321.0833
7  2010     1  21 318.4167
8  2010     1  22 317.6667
9  2010     1  23 319.0000
10 2010     1  24 321.0833
11 2010     1  25 323.5417
12 2010     1  26 326.0833
13 2010     1  27 328.4167
14 2010     1  28 330.9583
15 2010     1  29 333.2917
16 2010     1  30 335.7917
17 2010     1  31 308.0000
>
```

Note that temperatures are stored in tenths of degrees in this data set, so for the period between January 15th and 31st 2010, the average daily temperatures at the Dulles International Airport weather station were between 30.8 degrees and 33.5 degrees.

Also note that to calculate the average by `stationId` and run across multiple weather stations, simply add `station` to the `aggregate()` function.

```
> # summarize to average daily temps by station
> aggregate(value ~ station + year + month + day,mean,data = data)
             station year month day    value
1  GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  15 323.5417
2  GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  16 322.8750
3  GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  17 323.4167
4  GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  18 323.7500
5  GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  19 323.2083
6  GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  20 321.0833
7  GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  21 318.4167
8  GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  22 317.6667
9  GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  23 319.0000
10 GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  24 321.0833
11 GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  25 323.5417
12 GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  26 326.0833
13 GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  27 328.4167
14 GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  28 330.9583
15 GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  29 333.2917
16 GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  30 335.7917
17 GHCND:USW00093738 2010     1  31 308.0000
>
```